# How to Track AWS Resource created by an IAM user and store record in database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created some IAM users to my AWS account with permission to launch instances.
Now I want to track and store their instance launch activity like time and instance ID in my MySQL or any other database.

Is there any way to achieve this, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All activities of an IAM user can be monitored using aws cloudtrail. Cloudtrail logs all the events.
The cloudtrail log is stored to a S3 bucket. You can use the storage trigger option in aws lambda functions to watch for a particular log .

In this case the log for new EC2 instance creation. 
In the lambda function you need to add the code that takes that log information and stores into a Mysql database that you have setup.

Refer this post https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail.html

Also you can try creating a cloudwatch for EC2 instance creation and it can trigger an aws lambda function which will do the data insert to the db. 
Here is a sample of cloudwatch based scheduler. You have to setup a specific trigger as per your need though.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Comment: Aravind, Thank you for your suggestion, It's really a good idea you have given and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html):

> CloudTrail is enabled on your AWS account when you create it. When activity occurs in your AWS account, that activity is recorded in a CloudTrail event. You can easily view recent events in the CloudTrail console by going to Event history. For an ongoing record of activity and events in your AWS account, create a **trail**.